# Change background color of jQuery autocomplete item based on state (using CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, background, jquery-autocomplete

The goal is to create a JQuery autocomplete element whose list items have a blue background when they're hovered over or focused via the keyboard. The Facebook search box pulls this off nicely.

Each `<li>` element contains custom HTML wrapped in an `<a>`. Each of those `<a>` tags belongs to the class `sbiAnchor`. Generating the blue background on hover can be done successfully using the following CSS:

```
.ui-autocomplete a.ui-corner-all.sbiAnchor:hover{
    background: blue;
}
```

But how does one apply that same blue background when the user keys up/down the autocomplete list. Changing the CSS code to the following does NOT work:

```
.ui-autocomplete a.ui-corner-all.sbiAnchor:hover, .ui-autocomplete .ui-state-focus a.ui-corner-all.sbiAnchor{
    background: blue;
}
```

What's the correct approach here? Keep in mind that this blue background effect should only apply to one specific autocomplete on my page (several of them exist). That's why I'm using sbiAnchor to differentiate its items from those of the other autocomplete elements. The other autocompletes should retain their default behavior so the CSS selectors shouldn't be too broad.

Answer (score 24):

This work quite easy

```
body .ui-autocomplete {
  /* font-family to all */
}

body .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item .ui-corner-all {
   /* all <a> */
}

body .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item .ui-state-focus {
   /* selected <a> */
}
```

Comment: `body .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item.ui-state-focus {
   /* selected <a> */
}`   There is a space between the last two classes when there shouldn't be

Answer (score 13):

I've changed the color by:

```
.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active,
a.ui-button:active,
.ui-button:active,
.ui-button.ui-state-active:hover {
}
```

Comment: That's the respective style in jquery-ui.css and with that the only appropriate answer. All the other answers have side effects.

Answer (score 12):

the css of hover become form this css class
[image]

you can override it .
for example:

```
.ui-state-focus {
background: none !important;
background-color: blue !important;
border: none !important;}
```

Comment: Heads up: overriding this class doesn't work without the !important flag for me

Answer (score 7):

This changed the hover color for me.

```
.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover
{
    border: none !important;
    background-color: #your-color;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used above answers and tweaked little bit to work for my scenario (Hovering styling for JQuery autocomplete items). Hopefully this helps someone.

```
.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
    background: #6693bc !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Input fields rather than anchor tags hold focus.  This should work.

```
.ui-autocomplete-input:focus, .ui-autocomplete a.ui-corner-all.sbiAnchor:hover {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the correct answer: just change the "grey" by the color you want

```css
.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active,
a.ui-button:active,
.ui-button:active,
.ui-button.ui-state-active:hover {
 border: none!important;
 background: grey;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Don't you think *"here is the correct answer"* is a tad arrogant? Certainly when this question already has a much upvoted answer, while yours unnecessarily repeats `.ui-state-active` and `ui-button:active`, also potentially affecting more than only the autocomplete elements mentioned in the question...

Comment: Well i'm sorry if you took it that way, I didn't mean to be arrogant... in fact, I tried the upvoted answers but they didn't work for me, so I posted quickly  the code that worked for me without thinking about the comment.

Comment: Thank you. For me it was the only answer that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.ui-menu-item` and `ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active`:

```
.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
  background: #f5f5f5 !important; 
  border: solid 1px transparent; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a while to figure it out but the correct CSS code is:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.sbiAnchor.ui-state-hover{
    background: blue;
}
```

This kills two birds with one stone, providing a blue background for both hover **and** selection via up/down keystrokes. The jQuery autocomplete element apparently treats the up/down keystrokes as a "hover" action, not a selection or focus.

Answer (score 0):

Such an old topic, but the solutions above haven't worked for me. If I would have gone straight forward, I would have been much faster in finding a solution:

Overwrite in your custom stylesheet the following style of jquery-ui.css

```
.ui-autocomplete {
            border-radius: 0.25rem;
            background-color: #eceff1;
            padding: 0 0.6rem;
            font-family: 'ptmono';
        .ui-menu-item {
            border: 1px solid #eceff1;
            border-radius: 0.25rem;
            .ui-state-active,
    .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
    .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active,
    a.ui-button:active,
    .ui-button:active,
    .ui-button.ui-state-active:hover {
            background-color: #eceff1;
            border-color: #eceff1;
            color: #0d47a1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of background: none !important, you can set the background in .ui-menu-item and in the active class. Additionally instead of writing border: none !important you overwrite in both classes the border color with the background color, what prevents a change of the height and with that a wobble effect.